# Kernel functions for vectors in discrete spaces

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process, kernel-trick

There are lots of choices for kernel functions $k(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y})$ in continuous spaces (e.g., $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^d$), such as the RBF kernel, etc.
However, what are some common kernel functions for vectors on discrete spaces (e.g., $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \in\{0,1\}^d$, or even $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \in\{1,\dots,K\}^d$)?

Comment: the main kernel I see on discrete data is the polynomial kernel, but I don't use kernel methods much in practice so I'm curious to see what others say

Answer (score 2):

When $\mathcal{I}$ is a finite set with $m$ elements, a Gaussian
Process (GP) $Y_i$ with index $i \in \mathcal{I}$ is nothing but a
Gaussian random vector with length $m$, and a positive kernel defined
on $\mathcal{I}$ is nothing but a symmetric and positive semi-definite
$m \times m$ matrix. Special structures of matrices such as *Compound
Symmetry* or block matrices can be interesting: Many such structures
can be found in the literature on mixed effects e.g. in [Pinheiro and
Bates](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2Fb98882).
Parameterised forms involving only a few parameters should be preferred
because the number of observations can easily be exceeded by the
number of parameters which can be as high as $m(m + 1)/2$ for the
so-called *unconstrained* structure. When $\mathcal{I}$ is the product
of $d$ finite sets, parameterised kernels on $\mathcal{I}$ can be
obtained as tensor products.

Some covariance structures correspond to a representation of the GP as
a sum of GP. As an example, a GP $Y_i$ with the Compound Symmetry
structure writes as $Y_i = \alpha + \beta_i$ where the effects
$\alpha$ and the $m$ r.vs $\beta_i$ are independent and $\sum_i
\beta_i = 0$. So by adding a white noise term $\varepsilon$ at right
hand side, the GP regression boils down to a classical random effect
model. More complex structures implying unobserved effects can be
obtained, and the estimated (or *smoothed*) values of the effects
can be interesting.  It should be kept in mind then that the kernel
acts as a Bayes informative prior. Consequently, the estimators of the
effects are shrinked.  Standard fixed-effects ANOVA models correspond
instead to diffuse priors which are limits of ''large'' covariance matrices
such as $\lambda \mathbf{I}$ for $\lambda \to \infty$.

A kernel $K$ on a continuous (infinite) set $\mathcal{X}$ relates to
interesting bases of functions in some *infinite-dimensional* space of
functions defined on $\mathcal{X}$. By contrast, the space of all
functions on a finite set $\mathcal{I}$ is finite-dimensional:
choosing a basis boils down to translating an ANOVA model formula.

Answer (score 1):

One way to construct kernels over discrete spaces is by considering a graph representation of the data and defining a smooth function over nodes of graphs via graph fourier transform. This class of kernels (introduced by Kondor and Lafferty)  is called as [diffusion kernels](https://www.ml.cmu.edu/research/dap-papers/kondor-diffusion-kernels.pdf). Concretely, the kernel over the graph nodes $V$ is given by:
\begin{align}
K(V,V) = \exp(-\beta L) = U \exp(-\beta \Lambda) U^T
\end{align}
where $L$ is the graph laplacian, $U$, $\Lambda$ represent the eigenvector and eigenvalue matrices of L. Please note that each input is assumed to be one node of the constructed graph. This approach also has very nice [connections](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~risi/papers/KondorVert04.pdf) to heat equation in continuous spaces.